# gitlab-ci: ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to create a pipeline to build my app, but I'm getting this error inside the job:

```
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
$ docker info
Client:
 Version:    24.0.6
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.11.2
    Path:     /usr/local/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.21.0
    Path:     /usr/local/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
Server:
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
errors pretty printing info
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```yaml
variables: 
  ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN: "yes"
  GIT_SUBMODULE_STRATEGY: recursive
#  DOCKER_HSOT: tcp://docker:2375


stages:
  - build

build:
  stage: build
  image: docker
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker info
    - docker run hello-world
```

As [suggested here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab/-/issues/478#note_82995205), I've tried different values for `DOCKER_HOST`, but none of them work:

```
tcp://docker:2375
tcp://docker:2376
tcp://localhost:2376
tcp://localhost:2375
```

How can I fix this?

When I run `docker run --rm -ti --privileged docker:dind` in my local machine, I can see that these ports are availabe:

```
λ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE           COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS                                       NAMES
4444eac40b2f   docker:dind     "dockerd-entrypoint.…"   36 seconds ago   Up 35 seconds               2375-2376/tcp                               focused_meitner
047918cd1a36   docker:dind     "dockerd-entrypoint.…"   29 minutes ago   Exited (1) 29 minutes ago                                               gifted_northcutt
4debeab175d6   docker:dind     "dockerd-entrypoint.…"   29 minutes ago   Exited (1) 29 minutes ago                                               compassionate_black
```

But for the job, nothing is printed:

```
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
$ docker ps -a
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375. Is the docker daemon running?
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

Comment: If you're self-hosting your runner, can you show the runner configuration?

Comment: @sytech I'm not self-hosting the runner. It's a shared runner that's created by the provider.

Comment: Try adding the same commands you are running locally to the CI job. It mentions on the docker hub docker image page that —privelaged flag is required to start a daemon. https://hub.docker.com/_/docker @AmirShabani

Answer (score 0):

It might be the docker daemon (dind) is not started yet. Try to play adding `sleep 30` before the `docker info` command. And keep `tcp://docker:2375` with `DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""` in case you use Docker Executor without TLS.